# Why Datanode process didn't run in wsl?

Tags: hadoop, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have set up and configured my hadoop in wsl, but when I start dataNode, it did't work.
This is it's log

```
2020-03-24 23:47:08,788 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2020-03-24 23:47:09,809 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2020-03-24 23:47:10,199 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Invalid dfs.datanode.data.dir /mnt/d/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1/tmp/dfs/data : 
ExitCodeException exitCode=1: chmod: changing permissions of '/mnt/d/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1/tmp/dfs/data': Operation not permitted

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:728)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode$DataNodeDiskChecker.checkDir(DataNode.java:2344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2508)
2020-03-24 23:47:10,207 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.io.IOException: All directories in dfs.datanode.data.dir are invalid: "/mnt/d/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1/tmp/dfs/data/" 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2508)
2020-03-24 23:47:10,209 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2020-03-24 23:47:10,213 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at DESKTOP-U1EOV4J.localdomain/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

I want to let the dataNode and nameNode directory in my windows directory(such as in mnt/d/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1/tmp) but failed.

I tried to use `chmod 777 -R hadoop /mnt/d/hadoop`but it still can't start. Also I tired to delete the tmp directory and reformat namenode.

But when I change the directory to /home/hadoop/tmp(my wsl directory), dataNode can start normally.

According to the log file, I think this is a problem of authority but I don't konw why. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem, this is caused by windows authority.

You can't change the file's authority under /mnt in wsl.

When you use chown or chmod, they actually don't work.

You need to use the following instructions first.

```
sudo umount /mnt/d
sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d -o metadata
```

Then you can change the file's authority in wsl.

You can get more information here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/